# Entire (Mostly) Home's Lights Flicker when Resistive Loads are Energized

Tags: electrical, hvac, heating, neutral

Thanks for taking a look at my question. I am troubled by a strange issue that I think I may have an idea about, but I am not 100%. So I would appreciate anyone else's feedback to hopefully set me down the right path.

Basically, when I am using resistive loads around my home (ie. deep fryer, 3D printer) the lights around my home are flickering noticeably. Some more noticeable than others, but it would seem that most of them flicker or pulsate. My background in electro-mechanical engineering leads me to believe this may be due to PWM control of the resistive heating element in the appliances I listed above.

What I don't understand is why this is happening to nearly every circuit in my home while these appliances are in use. It strikes me as odd and potentially problematic that something operating on one 20A circuit would cause such a noticeable voltage fluctuation across other circuits. (For reference, this is an American home with 120/240v single-phase and a 150A service to the panel)

So with all of that, does anyone think there may be a bottle-neck somewhere in my electrical system? Before I moved in, the entire breaker panel was replaced because it was one of the dreadful *federal pacific* branded ones. If anyone has ideas on where I could start investigating it would be superb. And if it's of any help, I will add my findings as replies to this post.

Thanks!

Heres the panel:
[image]

Comment: I would check to make sure the neutral wires in the panel are all snug.  If you don't know how, then call an electrician, there's not really any safety guards at that point.

Comment: Type of lights?  LEDs are more sensitive to problems.  Any change if a 240v device is working?  Can you take voltage reading at different outlets?

Comment: After @Aaron 's suggestion, I found that one of my two neutral bars was not bonded to the other. They both have a ground bond, (a different ground!) [One ground bar is to my plumbing, the other is to the outdoor ground rod] but the left bar has no wire bonding it to the bar on the right, which is connected to the neutral coming from my service. I have some 8AWG around so I am going to bond them and move forward with my investigation.

Comment: Ground bonds only do with your safety, not if the circuit is working right.  Picture of your panel will help.  Both neutral bars should be bonded to each other, either by the steel of the panel or a rod/wire.  Are you sure they are both neutrals or neutral and ground?

Comment: @crip659 Yessir. There are two ground bars each with it's own, independent ground wire to different grounding locations. And two neutral bars, one of which is connected directly to the service neutral, the other is only bonded to a ground bar. Both neutral bars have a bond to ground. But not the same ground. I ran a 8AWG wire between the neutral bars, which now effectively guarantees all grounds and neutrals within the entire panel are at the same potential if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You have a panel made in May 2022 and zero GFCI or AFCI breakers? Kinda sus.

Comment: Note that the case itself (the gray steel thing they are all bolted to) connects all the ground bars connected to it, and the neutral that's bonded to it (and the two neutrals are bonded to each other behind the breakers.) Adding an explicit bond wire is not a bad thing, but not required, and it *would* be required if the case was not adequate.

Answer (score 2):

### A lost neutral?

Go outside and look at the wire coming from the utility pole to your house.  There is a bare carrier wire and two phase wires.  Look closely at the carrier wire at both ends.  Is it tied off to an anchor point, or is it broken off with the works hanging from the two phase wires? *Because that will do that*.  **That is a lost neutral from your utility**, and it will cause wobbly voltage. That will make cheaper LED bulbs go crazy because of the steep voltage-current curve on raw LEDs.

The other way to check for that is by looking at outlet voltages.  If some are higher than 120V but others are below 120V by equal amount.  Voltages won't get too extreme if your ground rods are working properly, since neutral can path through the dirt to your neighbor's ground rod.  It's not great, and that's why we bother to mine copper.

The utility will fix this fast and free if you report an outage, which is what it actually is.

Comment: I checked the carrier wire from the pole to my house and the points where it's terminated. It is a slightly smaller gauge than the wires from my utility meter, and it's quite corroded - but it looks to be properly terminated on both ends without any major issues. In my panel, the voltages seem normal. Between leg A and leg B, I get about 120v +/- 1v depending on time of day. Regardless, I see very little difference between the two legs, even under load.

Comment: @B-Dawg Are you able to check the voltages while operating an on/off electric heater of the same wattage? That would remove the PWM question, but then allow you to see if the load itself is enough to create a significant drop in the wiring. (Another slant at things would be to use an isolation transformer, but one large enough to handle the required power might be expensive to buy.)

Comment: @periblepsis When I checked voltages under load, I wasn't using any of the appliances that cause the issue at all. I kicked on my heat pump and dryer at the same time, which put a total load of about 9KW (read by my CT clamps). Under this load, at around 7:30PM local time, I was getting 120.1v on leg A, and 120.5v on leg B.

Comment: @B-Dawg The heat pump and dryer are on the 220-240 breaker pairs, right? But that may still tell me one thing -- your L1 and L2 to the house and into the panel aren't in terrible shape.

Comment: @B-Dawg you won't get a meaningful test with 240V loads.  You need heavy 120V loads on one of the two phases (i.e. all on L1 or all on L2) intentionally imbalanced to get a meaningful result. Here's the trouble we're looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg

Comment: Hair dryer, toaster, microwave oven  - that sort of thing.